# What would happen if we never included the additional diode on the secondary side of a Forward Converter?

Tags: diodes, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVzfUR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the schematic above I say additional diode because I considered that the Forward Converter is an isolated version of a Buck converter and the 'Additional Diode' is added when isolation is employed.

Why is it important? What will be the effect if this diode is removed?

Comment: D1 is not additional. D2 might be. Are you sure?

Comment: What is your understanding of this circuit, can you draw the waveforms? When does the diode conduct? What work have you done to try and figure this out so far?